# Integrating $f(x,y)=x/y$ over measurable region that has $(0,0)$ on its boundary.

Tags: integration

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the gray region in the following plot

[2dregion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rREbi.png)

$M$ is measurable. Furthermore, let $f(x,y)=x/y$. The question is, does $\int_M f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}(x,y)$ exist?

What I know is that if $M$ is measurable and $f$ continuous on the closure of $M$, then $f$ is integrable on $M$. But this is only sufficient.

In this example, $f$ is not defined on $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=0\}$ but $(0,0)$ is a point on the boundary of $M$. Therefore, I'm not sure if the following actually makes sense:

$\displaystyle{\int_0^1\int_{y/2}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{x}{y}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y+\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{y/2}^{1/y}\frac{x}{y}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}$.

I can solve both double integrals and the point $(0,0)$ does not seem to cause any issues but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems correct. Both $x$ and $y$ have positive sign in this quadrant, so the limit to $(0,0)$ should be fine.

To me it feels simpler to switch the order of integration between $x$ and $y$, like this:
$$
\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt2} \int_{x^2}^{2x} \frac{x}{y}dydx + \int_{1/\sqrt2}^1 \int_{x^2}^{1/x} \frac{x}{y}dydx
$$

Comment: The OP's solution looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks much for the response. Can "...so the limit to $(0,0)$ should be fine" be made more explicit? The sufficient condition that I mentioned above requires $f$ to be continuous on the closure of $M$. In my case $f$ is not defined in $(0,0)$ and therefore also not continuous there. So before splitting the area integral into the sum of two double integrals (as I and you did), I would like to know by a rigorous argument that this is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes perfect sense, in the same way that e.g. $\int_0^1x^{-\frac12}dx$ makes sense. Although the integrand is not defined at $x=0$, the integral over any interval $[\varepsilon,1]$ is well-defined for $0<\varepsilon<1$, and is bounded above by $2$. As the integrand is non-negative everywhere, this is enough to establish integrability on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it doesn't convince me yet because on the other hand $\int_0^1 x^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges. What I'm looking for is a rigorous argument that I can calculate the integral like that. I believe it can be but it feels a little casual as $f$ is not defined at $(0,0)$. When solving this integral in a rigorous manner, would I actually need to use a limiting process (improper integration)? But then the issue at $(0,0)$ does not seem to be relevant. I don't know if I was able to formulate my worries in an understandable way.

Comment: The integral of your $x^{-1}$ over $[\varepsilon,1]$ is not bounded above. This is the crucial difference. You don't say whether you mean Riemann or Lebesgue integration, so I can't be more specific; but neither of these is very difficult to apply if you go back to the definition.

Comment: The integration is meant in the Riemannian sense.